# Regex, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

### Warm up: Regex, Paper, Scissors

This is the challenge I originally wanted to post, before realising that some very short solution exist. Nevertheless, it can be an interesting problem to think about in preparation for the actual challenge below.

Write three regexes **R**, **P** and **S** such that they match each other in a cyclic Rock, Paper, Scissors fashion. In particular, **R** matches **S**, **S** matches **P** and **P** matches **R**, but **R** *doesn't* match **P**, **S** *doesn't* match **R** and **P** doesn't match **S**. Here's a handy table:

```
Regex   Matches   Doesn't match
R       S         P
P       R         S
S       P         R
```

It doesn't matter what **R**, **P** and **S** do on any other inputs, including themselves.

Here, **match** just means that some (possibly empty) substring of the input is matched. The match does not need to cover the entire input.

### The challenge: Regex, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock

For this challenge, you'll solve a tougher version of the above problem, based on the RPS variant Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock (as popularised by *The Big Bang Theory*). In RPSLV, there are five different symbols, that beat each other in two cycles:

- Rock → Scissors → Lizard → Paper → Spock → Rock
- Rock → Lizard → Spock → Scissors → Paper → Rock

You should write five regexes **R**, **P**, **S**, **L** and **V** which mimic this structure when given to each other as input. Here is the corresponding table:

```
Regex   Matches   Doesn't match
R       L, S      V, P
L       V, P      S, R
V       S, R      P, L
S       P, L      R, V
P       R, V      L, S
```

Just to be clear, you should *not* match the string `R`, `P`, etc, but the other regexes. E.g. if your regex **R** is `^\w$` for example, then **P** and **V** have to match the string `^\w$`, whereas **S** and **L** shouldn't.

Again, **match** just means that at least one (possibly empty) substring of the input is matched. The match does not need to cover the entire input. For example `\b` (word boundary) matches `hello` (at the beginning and at the end), but it doesn't match `(^,^)`.

You may use any regex flavour, but please state the choice in your answer and, if possible, provide a link to an online tester for the chosen flavour. You may not use any regex features that let you invoke code in the flavour's host language (like the Perl flavour's `e` modifier).

Delimiters (like `/regex/`) are not included in the regex when given as input to another, and you cannot use modifiers that are outside of the regex. Some flavours still let you use modifiers with inline syntax like `(?s)`.

Your score is the sum of the lengths of the five regexes in bytes. Lower is better.

It turns out to be a lot simpler to find *a* working solution to this problem than it may seem at first, but I hope that finding an optimal solution is quite tricky.

Comment: Does, say, R have to match the entire regex of S or a substring of S, provided it does not match any substrings of P or V?

Comment: @Okx "match just means that at least one (possibly empty) substring of the input is matched. The match does not need to cover the entire input. For example `\b` (word boundary) matches `hello` (at the beginning and at the end), but it doesn't match `(^,^)`."

Comment: Presumably it doesn't matter if a regex matches itself?

Comment: @Brilliand Correct.

Comment: For making this more general, could one just write a set of programs which accept (or reject) each other?

Comment: @MartinEnder I didn't want to generalize the graph, but to generalize from regular expressions to any kind of programs which implement a string → boolean function, in order to allow more "programming languages".

Comment: Great puzzle. I've created an interactive version here, if anyone is interested: https://shark.fish/rock-paper-scissors/

Comment: @shark.dp Wow that's really cool, nice work!

Answer (score 47):

## PCRE, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Rock:
`B`

Paper:
`\b$`

Scissors:
`b|B.`

Lizard:
`\B.`

Spock:
`^\w`

Comment: Very impressive.

Comment: Unbeatable! I've been fiddling with Rock = `Q` (one 14b solution exists with Lizard = `\Q\\`, then the rest similar to yours) but to absolutely no avail.

Answer (score 46):

## <s>PCRE</s> .NET, <s>35</s> 32 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

Rock:

```
([*?]$)
```

Paper:

```
[)$]$+
```

Scissors:

```
[+?]$.*
```

Lizard:

```
[+$]$.?
```

Spock:

```
[*)]$
```

The idea here is to match characters at the end of other regexes which are reserved regex characters, but stop being treated as such when inside a character class.

Comment: Okay, you win :P

Comment: Sneaky use of putting things *after* the EOL "$" that become ignored when actively used and matchable when passively used

Answer (score 40):

### no fancy features, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

5 bytes saved by Neil's idea which uses that `]` needs no `\`.

This works for example with the python `re` module.

```
R='[SLR]]'
P='[RVP]]'
S='[PLS]]'
L='[PVL]]'
V='[SRV]]'
```

It searches for a `]` preceded by a letter that indicates which rule it is.

Previous version used `R='\[[RSL]'` etc.

An earlier attempt with score 40 was using `R='[SL]x|Rx'` etc.

Comment: Save 5 bytes by reversing everything: `R='[LSR]]'` etc.

Comment: @Neil That's a great improvement, thanks!

Comment: `This works with python's re` well, Python should probably be the header then

Comment: @cat I also wrote "for example", the whole sentence is just to say something concrete that I actually tried. I guess I could say POSIX like some others did, but I think my header is quite correct.

Answer (score 26):

## PCRE, <s>20</s> 19

Rock

```
W
```

Paper

```
^\w
```

Scissors

```
^\W
```

Spock

```
w?\x57$
```

Lizard

```
[w]W?
```

Answer (score 21):

## 20 bytes

```
R = 'R|VP'
L = 'L|RS'
V = 'V|LP'
S = 'S|RV'
P = 'P|LS'
```

Comment: Oh wow, it can be so easy!

Comment: That's beautiful.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, 45 bytes

Another trivial solution.

```
R:
^R|^.[SL]
P:
^P|^.[RV]
S:
^S|^.[PL]
L:
^L|^.[PV]
V:
^V|^.[SR]
```

Comment: Oh just realised my answer is a longer/similar version of yours, want me to delete it?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder All the answers currently are just longer/shorter versions of each other :p

Comment: I suppose haha...

Answer (score 6):

**POSIX, <s>50</s> 45 bytes**

```
Rock
.{5}RP?V?
Paper
.{5}PS?L?
Scissors
.{5}SR?V?
Lizard
.{5}LR?S?
Vulcan (Spock)
.{5}VP?L?
```

Could be done shorter but the (hide matches after $) trick got used, so I'm looking for another way

The first 5 chars of each string are ignored when matching. So the **effective** target string simplifies to just X?Y?. None of them have any double letters because "?" is an ordinary char, so the last 4 chars when used as a **regex** have to match (null string). So the patterns collapse down to "contains 5 chars followed by the target letter":  meaning  chars 6-9 of the target must contain the target letter (the 5th char in each string)

**Update: 35 byte version below, now!**

Comment: I always thought the **V** isn't actually for **V**ulcan but to represent the shape of the Vulcan salute (which is the hand gesture you use to represent Spock when playing RPSLV in person).

Comment: Anyway, welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer. I like that you've inverted the logic compared to all existing answers (matching only one letter and putting the letters beating the current regex into the regex).

Comment: Does POSIX automatically anchor the match to the beginning of the string? Otherwise, couldn't you drop those commas?

Comment: I think its POSIX. Could be perc. But yes, nicely spotted! 5 chars less!

Comment: And thanks for the welcome. Not that there's many golfs I know enough to tangle with or compete with jelly, but this one was nice!

Comment: There's no need to compete with Jelly. Just pick a language you like and enjoy yourself. :)

Answer (score 4):

## PCRE, 65 bytes

This is a really trivial solution - and not very clever at all - but I'll try to golf it.

V:

```
(?#V).+[SR]\)
```

L:

```
(?#L).+[PV]\)
```

S:

```
(?#S).+[PL]\)
```

P:

```
(?#P).+[RV]\)
```

R:

```
(?#R).+[SL]\)
```

Essentially, each regex has an 'identifier', in the form of a comment, which tells the other regexes whether it should be matched or not.

Answer (score 4):

## Vanilla RE, 40 characters

Not the most concise or elegant solution but has a pleasing quasi-semantic visual structure!

```
[^r][sl]
[^p][vr]
[^s][lp]
[^l][pv]
[^v][rs]
```

Rock beats Scissors or Lizard
Paper beats Vulcan or Rock
Scissors beats Lizard or Paper
Lizard beats Paper or Vulcan
Vulcan beats Rock or Scissors

Comment: I'm glad that someone posted the actual rules for Vulcan & Lizard.... I know Paper smothers a Rock, but how does a Paper defeat a Vulcan?  I suppose Wikipedia would yield the answer.  Yup: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors#Additional_weapons

Answer (score 3):

## .NET, 50 bytes

In order they are `R, P, S, L, V`.

```
[^R]\^[SL]
[^P]\^[RV]
[^S]\^[PL]
[^L]\^[PV]
[^V]\^[SR]
```

Works by looking for the identifier group (for example, `[^R]`) in each of the other expressions.

Changing the expressions to `^R|\^[SL]`, or similar, seems to work but then it's a bit too similar to @dzaima's answer although it would get it to 45 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

**POSIX, 35 bytes**

```
Rock
R?^[LS]
Paper
P?^[RV]
Scissors
S?^[LP]
Lizard
L?^[PV]
Vulcan (Spock)
V?^[RS]
```

A completely different way to "hide" behind a start/end symbol, so I feel OK about it :)  I'm matching to start because "?" would always have to go between letter and end/$ if done the other way.

10 bytes less than my 1st solution, and conceptually simple which is a bonus I like.